# How can I compute the inverse cross product of a vector in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vector

How can I perform the inverse cross product in numpy?

That is, given two numpy arrays `b` and `c`, how can I find `a` such that

```
a.cross(b) == c
```

**EDIT**: Could whoever downvoted please let me know what they didn't like it, so that I can learn from their opinion? I asked the question because I didn't easily find an answer anywhere. Turns out the question is mathematically ill-defined (as people pointed out), but from now on if people look it up here this answer will show up and they'll know that quickly and easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There only exists a solution if a and c are orthogonal, and the solution is not unique.

Then, a = np.cross(b,c)/np.dot(b,b)+t*b is a solution for all t.

See this question on Math SE:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32600/whats-the-opposite-of-a-cross-product

Comment: Whoops! Yes, I was being silly - of course it's undefined in the general case. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no function native to numpy that will arrive at the solution you're looking for. You may have better luck asking the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

There seems to be a problem with the question as well. From what I know of linear algebra, solving for 'a' wouldn't yield a unique solution unless certain conditions are met.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32602) over at the math stack exchange for more information.